# How to get session id for each IE instance?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

When I open two instance of IE, each IE instance should have separate id which is not happening in 2.0 framework, while in version 1.0 it was possible.

How to get session id for each IE instance?

Answer (score 3):

Its not problem with framework. IE 6 used to launch new session but in later versions, you get explicit option in File menu to open new window in new session

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string TheSessionId() {
     HttpSessionState ss = HttpContext.Current.Session;
     HttpContext.Current.Session["test"] = "test";
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ss.SessionID);
     return "ok";
}
```

Try the little function above to see if you are getting 2 different Session IDs.  If so, you'll just need to use the first line so that you can get your Session ID.